# Get groups of person

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to find a query to get all groups of a person.
I have seen that there is an attribute called **memberOf**, but I don't know how I can use it.

I found a query, but it doesn't work for me:

```
(&
    (objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)
    (uniqueMember=<user>)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With external command adfind (joeware) you can extract easily direct memberships by using following parameter:

```
adfind -f samaccountname=youraccount memberof -list
```

If you are searching all direct and nested group memberships, then a bit different filter search required:

```
adfind -f "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=Jim Smith,ou=West,dc=Domain,dc=com)" samaccountname -list
```

On this search you would get group samaccountname as an output, but you can add other attributes as well or replace samaccountname for example with displayname attribute.

More about the filters:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx

Comment: The external tool is required, isn't it?

Comment: Adfind is an external tool. If only quick export of some data is needed, that is very handy tool for that work.

Comment: If built-in tools are only allowed tools, then ldp can be used. Search filter is same still.